Is there a way to generate State Machine/Step Function CDK from Amazon State Language JSON generated by the online AWS Step Function GUI?
TLDR:
I'm Basically looking for the EXACT OPPOSITE OF Is there a way to get the Amazon State Language JSON representation of a State Machine created within AWS CDK
I just want to generate code like:
const definition = submitJob
  .next(waitX)
  .next(getStatus)
  .next(new sfn.Choice(this, 'Job Complete?')
    // Look at the "status" field
    .when(sfn.Condition.stringEquals('$.status', 'FAILED'), jobFailed)
    .when(sfn.Condition.stringEquals('$.status', 'SUCCEEDED'), finalStatus)
    .otherwise(waitX));


from JSON (not a one-to-one example):
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Is JWT header Present?",
  "States": {
    "Is JWT header Present?": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.header.Authorization",
          "IsPresent": false,
          "Next": "Pass"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Validate Request"
    },
    "Pass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "Validate Request",
      "Parameters": {
        "body.$": "$.body",
        "header": {
          "Authorization": ""
        },
        "querystring.$": "$.querystring",
        "path.$": "$.path"
      }
    },
  }
}

I have a bunch of JSON generated from AWS's online Step Function GUI. I've been copy/pasting them to local JSON and using:
  new sf.StateMachine(stack, 'Name', {
    stateMachineName: 'Name',
    definitionBody: sf.DefinitionBody.fromFile('/path/to/definition.json'),
    stateMachineType: sf.StateMachineType[stateMachineType],
    tracingEnabled: true,
  });

Locally, I use a step-functions local server to load the JSON like so (Secret/Key is from local NosqlWorkbench so don't worry):
PROVIDER_OVERRIDE_STEPFUNCTIONS=v2 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=3iy479 AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=23ka8k java -jar ./sf/StepFunctionsLocal.jar --dynamodb-endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8000 --lambda-endpoint http://127.0.0.1:3001 --step-functions-endpoint http://localhost:8083
aws stepfunctions --endpoint-url=http://localhost:8083 create-state-machine --name=foobar', --role-arn=arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/DummyRole --definition=file://path/to/file.json 

Unfortunately I hit a wall with local development when I started executing Step Functions from within Step Functions. The ARN of the inside SF is not the same as my local stepfunction server. When I find & replace with my local ARN, it works fine.

Short answer - no, there isn't.
